# Not Parsing Through

Tags: python, for-loop

I tried to parse through a text file, and see the index of the character where the four characters before it are each different. Like this:

`wxrgh`

The h would be the marker, since it is after the four different digits, and the index would be 4. I would find the index by converting the text into an array, and it works for the test but not for the actually input. Does anyone know what is wrong.

```
def Repeat(x):
    size = len(x)
    repeated = []
    for i in range(_size):
        k = i + 1
        for j in range(k, _size):
            if x[i] == x[j] and x[i] not in repeated:
                repeated.append(x[i])
    return repeated
```

```
with open("input4.txt") as f:
    text = f.read()
    test_array = []
    split_array = list(text)
    woah = ""
    for i in split_array:
        first = split_array[split_array.index(i)]
        second = split_array[split_array.index(i) + 1]
        third = split_array[split_array.index(i) + 2]
        fourth = split_array[split_array.index(i) + 3]
        test_array.append(first)
        test_array.append(second)
        test_array.append(third)
        test_array.append(fourth)
        print(test_array)
        if Repeat(test_array) != []:
            test_array = []
        else:
            woah = split_array.index(i)
        print(woah)

    print(woah)
```

I tried a test document and unit tests but that still does not work

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilise a *set* to help you with this.

Read the entire file into a list (buffer). Iterate over the buffer starting at offset 4. Create a set of the 4 characters that precede the current position. If the length of the set is 4 (i.e., they're all different) and the character at the current position is not in the set then you've found the index you're interested in.

```
W = 4
with open('input4.txt') as data:
    buffer = data.read()
    for i in range(W, len(buffer)):
        if len(s := set(buffer[i-W:i])) == W and buffer[i] not in s:
            print(i)
```

**Note:**

If the input data are split over multiple lines you may want to remove newline characters.

You will need to be using Python 3.8+ to take advantage of the assignment expression (walrus operator)

Comment: What if I wanted to change it from 4 to 14

Comment: @RiyaNRocks Change the assignment to W from 4 to 14

Comment: It still says the answer is wrong

Comment: @RiyaNRocks Show your file content and the value you're using for W

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1tqMuR-Al53jqn93I8YPfFH128cHltQms8WlMfAiUqSA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @RiyaNRocks That gives an output of 3622. Are you saying that's wrong? What should the output be?

Comment: I am not aware, this is part of the advent of code. It says the answer is too high